# Populating Inner HTML In Each Statement

Tags: jquery

I on success of an ajax call I am trying to populate each items real_price. What its doing is populating all the real_price tags of every item to the last value the service picks up.

How can I rewrite it to populate 1 at a time so every item has their specific price?

```
<div class="item">
    <p class="price">$388.00</p>
    <p class="part_number">VM2327T23A00T</p>
    <p class="real_price"></p>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <p class="price">$88.00</p>
    <p class="part_number">AA327T23A00T</p>
    <p class="real_price"></p>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <p class="price">$38.00</p>
    <p class="part_number">AA327T23A00T</p>
    <p class="real_price"></p>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery('.part_number').each(function () {

                jQuery.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "RealTimePricing.aspx/GetRealPrice",
                    data: "{pmber:' " + SearchSpring.jQuery(this).text() + "', lrice: ' " + jQuery(this).siblings('.price').text() + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (msg) {
                       //NEED TO CHANGE SOMETHING HERE
                       jQuery('.real_price').html(msg.d);
</script>
```

Comment: `jQuery(this).find('.real_price')`.

Comment: use jQuery('.real_price').text(msg.d)

Comment: what does response data look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First argument of `$(selector).each(function( index, element)` is the index of element. Using that index can target the corresponding `real_price` element using eq() method

```
jQuery('.part_number').each(function (index) {

                jQuery.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "RealTimePricing.aspx/GetRealPrice",
                    data: "{pmber:' " + SearchSpring.jQuery(this).text() + "', lrice: ' " + jQuery(this).siblings('.price').text() + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (msg) {
                       //NEED TO CHANGE SOMETHING HERE
                       jQuery('.real_price').eq(index).html(msg.d);
```

Alternately can define element in refernce to `this` which will require less DOM searching

```
jQuery('.part_number').each(function (index) {
    var $real_price=$(this).next();

     /* ajax */

        success: function(msg){
            $real_price.html( msg.d);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the sibling of that class:

```
jQuery('.part_number').each(function (i, el) {
//...
    success: function (msg) {
        jQuery(el).siblings('.real_price').html(msg.d);
    }
//...
});
```

Comment: I actually tried that before the post but it doesnt seem to be working

Comment: I think the problem might be the `this` in the success callback.  Before the call to `jQuery.ajax` store `this` in another variable, something like `var that = this;` and then try `jQuery(that).siblings('.real_price').html(msg.d);`

Comment: @MrOBrian yeah that was dumb of me. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The information provided is slightly lacking, but if I understand you correctly you are wanting to update each "real_price" with the corresponding value.

Based off of that assumption something along the following should work:

```
success: function(msg){
    for(var i=0; msg.length; i++){
        var obj = msg[i];

        $('.item').each(function(k, v){
            if($(this).find('.part_number').text() == obj.part_number){
                $(this).find('.real_price').text(obj.real_price);
            }
        });
    }
}
```